# Linear algebra proofs - traces, symmetricity and inversion

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a few proofs I need some help with.

**a)** Prove that $AB-BA = I$ does not have any solutions for any $A,B$. All matrices are regular.

I based my proof on matrix traces. $tr(AB) = tr(BA)$. Since $tr(X+Y) = tr(X) + tr(Y)$, it holds that $tr(AB - BA) = tr(AB) - tr(BA) = 0$ and $tr(I) = m$ so the diagonal numbers cant be "önes". Is this proof correct or do I have to use some other method?

**b)** Prove that $(AB)^{-1} = B^{-1}A^{-1}$. I believe that I can prove this by simply writing all the matrices products down.. is there some simplier and more "elegant" way how to prove this?

**c)** Prove that $A + A^T$ is symetric for a square $A$. Not sure abotu this one...

Thanks for any help in advance!

EDIT: $A$ in c) is square, not rectangular!

Comment: Your proof of (a) is correct and for (b), if you mean just computing $(B^{-1}A^{-1})(AB)$ and $(AB)(B^{-1}A^{-1})$, then that's the canonical proof. As for (c), what is the definition of a symmetric matrix?

Comment: a) and b) are good, for c), check first how transpose acts with sums. That is, how is $(A + B)^T$ related to $A^T$ and $B^T$.

Comment: Note that you don't need to compute _both_ $(B^{-1}A^{-1})(AB)$ and $(AB)(B^{-1}A^{-1})$ if $A$ and $B$ are matrices (i.e. linear maps on a _finite-dimensional_ vector space), as one of them will suffice in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) The proof is fine

b) More "elegant" proof (to me) would be the argument "invertible matrices form a group with the group operation as matrix multiplication"

c) Are you sure $A$ is rectangular. Let us say $A$ is $2 \times 4$, so $A^T$ is $4 \times 2$, Now thinking about adding two matrices $A$ and $A^T$ which are of different size.

Comment: edit! A is square... sorry for this

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple other ways to do (a) as well.

For (b), you could reason straight from the definition of the inverse of a matrix as follows. Let $X=AB$ and $Y=B^{-1}A^{-1}$. Now $$XY=(AB)(B^{-1}A^{-1})=ABB^{-1}A^{-1}=AIA^{-1}=AA^{-1}=I,$$ and similarly $YX=I$. Therefore, $Y=X^{-1}$.

In (c), you must mean *square* rather than rectangular. If so, then $$(A+A^T)^T=A^T+(A^T)^T=A+A^T$$ and thus $A+A^T$ is symmetric.

Answer (score 0):

So **a** and **b** are correct. Thanks

As for **c**, I believe it goes like this

$A = 
\begin{bmatrix}
 a_{1,1} & \dots & a_{1,n} \\
 \dots \\
 a_{n,1} & \dots & a_{n,n}
\end{bmatrix}$

$A^T = 
\begin{bmatrix}
 a_{1,1} & \dots & a_{n,1} \\
 \dots \\
 a_{1,n} & \dots & a_{n,n}
\end{bmatrix}$

so
$A + A^T = 
\begin{bmatrix}
 2a_{1,1} & \dots & a_{1,n} +a_{n,1} \\
 \dots \\
 a_{n,1} + a_{1,n} & \dots & 2a_{n,n}
\end{bmatrix}$
which is symetric.. correct?

Comment: That's correct, but you don't even need to go into that detail, if you recall that $(A+B)^T = A^T + B^T$ and that $(A^T)^T = A$.

Comment: Perhaps you mean $A$ is *square* rather than *rectangular*.

Comment: Yes - my mistake.. I edited the post

Comment: Let C = A + $A^T $ then $C^T$ = C